# Carousel with open image on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need a specific carousel that have, for example, 4 visible slides from 10 and you can scroll through each of them. When you click on thumb, it opens image on top.

Below follows an image:

[image: 1]

I used lots of sliders but did not found what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the container the Carousel is in a background image then use some jquery to change the background image when one of the pictures is clicked.

Surround each image with

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="img1"></a>
```

then use jquery

```
$('#img1').on('click', function() {
    $('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url(bg1.jpg)');
})
```

finally in css

```
#changeMe {
    background-image: url(bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

edit see http://www.bootply.com/PCAYskJ3Tl for quick example