# Bootstrap carousal: open the clicked image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am making a lightbox - carousel - modal page with Bootstrap 3. So far, all is going very well, except for one thing: 
When the carousel starts, it always starts at the very first image of the page, not the image that I click on.
In other words: if I click on image 1 then image 1 is opened, if I click on image 2, then image 1 is opened, if I click on image 3, then image 1 is opened.
After that, the carousel works like it should, but what I want is, that when I click on image 2, that image 2opens, and if I click on image 3, that image 3 opens.

Some code:

```
  <ul class="cropped-images">
    <li class="la active"><a data-content="No 1" href="#lightbox" data-toggle="modal" data-slide-to="0"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="No 1"></a></li>
    <li class="la"><a data-content="No 2" href="#lightbox" data-toggle="modal" data-slide-to="1"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="No 2"></a></li>
    <li class="la"> etc... </ul>

    <div id="lightbox" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">  
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">TITLE</h4>
                            </div>
             <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
             <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/large/1.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">One Image</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/large/2.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">Another Image</div>
                  </div>
                  ... etc...
                  <!-- Controls -->
                  controls code
               </div>
             </div> 
          </div>
       </div>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carousel with open image on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835391/carousel-with-open-image-on-click)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) to create your own custom lightbox, something as shown that I've tried to show in the snippet below, please have a look:

```js
 $('.content-holder .thumbnail').each(function(i) {
 var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
 var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
 var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");

 item.attr("title", title);
 $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
 item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
 if (i === 0) { // set first item active
   item.addClass('active');
 }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval: false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
  var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
  var id = parseInt(idx);
  $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
  $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
 height: 100px;
 margin: 6px;
}

.thumbnail {
 margin-bottom: 6px;
}


.carousel-control.left {
 background-image: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 width: 25px;
 height: 100%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-control.right {
 background-image: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 0;
 width: 25px;
 height: 100%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item .thumbnail {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
 margin: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="content-holder">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" title="">
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" title="">
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- lightbox modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Lightbox</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- end lightbox modal -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: appreciated, but I've got something in place that is working, only need to find out how I can start with any image (not just the first one) from within the lightbox..

Comment: This deserves more points. I was searching exactly this. Thanks for your time

Comment: That's my pleasure @Poemko

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like this.

Just replace below line in your html code

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
```

to

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```